# Is multiple ChannelPipelineFactories possible for UDP transport in Netty

Tags: java, sockets, udp, netty

In Netty if I create multiple `ConnectionlessBootstrap` instances and then set the `ChannelPipeline` on them using code like `udpBootstrap.setPipeline(pipelineFactory.getPipeline());` 
Will the `DatagramChannel`'s created using following code:-

```
DatagramChannel datagramChannel = (DatagramChannel) udpBootstrap
                .bind(new InetSocketAddress(host, 0));
```

have the appropriate decoders and encoders in its pipeline based on the factory? Or irrespective of the bootstrap/pipelinefactory, `DatagramChannel`'s can have only one associated pipeline.

Scenario is that I want to use UDP to decode/encode different network protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the ChannelPipeline directly then they will share the same ChannelPipeline contents. If you want a different one per Channel you should set the ChannelPipelineFactory.